# Background worker still freezing ui

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Even tho I setup a background worker, I can't seem to make it not freeze the UI.

I looked around online but could not find a fix. I have tried creating basic threads and that worked but I need to also update UI stuff as it runs so thats why I switched to backgroundworkers, but if you could help me figure out how to use a basic thread and get that working that would be ok.

```
using MediaToolkit;
using MediaToolkit.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VideoLibrary;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<VideoInfo> vids = new List<VideoInfo>();
    private List<VideoInfo> failedVids = new List<VideoInfo>();
    private int threads = 0;
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    private delegate void DELEGATE();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.ShowDialog();
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(threads == 0)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = vids.Count;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            failedVids.Clear();
            worker.DoWork += doWork;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            //downloadVid();
        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for threads" + threads);
        }
        /*Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(downloadVid));
        thread1.Start();*/
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoInfo vid = new VideoInfo(tbLink.Text, tbTitle.Text, tbArtist.Text);
        vids.Add(vid);
        tbLink.Clear();
        tbTitle.Clear();
        listView1.Items.Add(vid.getLink());
    }

    private int downloadThread(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        var source = @"C:\Users\derri\Downloads\DownloadTest\";
        var youtube = YouTube.Default;
        VideoInfo vidInfo = vids[(int) i];
        var vid = youtube.GetVideo(vidInfo.getLink());
        Console.WriteLine(vidInfo.getLink());
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(source + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            failedVids.Add(vids[(int)i]);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            goto End;
        }

        var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = source + vid.FullName };
        var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = $"{source + vidInfo.getArtist() + " - " + vidInfo.getTitle()}.mp3" };

        using (var engine = new Engine())
        {
            engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

            engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
        }
        File.Exists(outputFile.Filename);
        File.Delete(inputFile.Filename);
        setTags(vidInfo.getArtist(), vidInfo.getTitle());
    End:
        threads--;
        return 1;
    }

    private void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Delegate del = new DELEGATE(downloadVid);
        this.Invoke(del);
    }

    private void downloadVid()
    {
        int prog = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vids.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            while ((threads > 5)) { }
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => { prog += downloadThread(i); });
            thread.Start();
            threads++;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //thread.Join();
            /*ParameterizedThreadStart start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(downloadThread);
            Thread t = new Thread(start);
            t.Start(i);
            progressBar1.Value++;
            threads++;*/

        }

        while (threads > 0){}
        foreach (VideoInfo failedVid in failedVids)
        {
            listView2.Items.Add(failedVid.getLink());
        }
        listView1.Clear();
        vids.Clear();

    }

    private void setTags(string artist, string title)
    {
        TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create("C:\\Users\\derri\\Downloads\\DownloadTest\\" + artist + " - " + title + ".mp3");
        file.Tag.Artists = (new String[] { artist });
        file.Tag.Title = (title);
        file.Save();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this.Invoke will run it on the UI thread. Why are you invoking it like that? I see the problem, the while loop blocks the UI because you are in the UI thread.

Comment: @RonBeyer I was following online tutorials and that is where they put the this.invoke and it was working for them. How would I go about not invoking it on the UI?

Comment: Just call `downloadVid` from the `doWork` method, or put all the `downloadVid` stuff inside `doWork`, either way don't use `this.Invoke` because you are effectively bypassing the background worker and running on the UI thread again. You'll have to make sure to call the `listview` methods on the UI thread though.

Comment: @RonBeyer That's the whole reason I am doing this the way I am. Its the only way I could find to be able to call the listview method from the UI thread. How do I do what you said and call the listview method from the UI thread?

Comment: I suspect that running `while ((threads > 5)) { }` on the main UI thread might be causing you some grief.

Comment: Also modifying the variable `threads` from multiple threads is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.Invoke will run on the UI thread.

Look into how to use either ReportProgress or RunWorkerCompleted events of the BackgroundWorker class.  The both allow you to pass data from the background thread to the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, new to threads in c# so thanks for giving me the info I would need to fix it without telling me.

Comment: Google is a great resource, here's a [link](https://nerdparadise.com/programming/csharpbackgroundworker) that explains the events I mentioned with an example.